# Convert user input to time which changes boolean value for the duration entered?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on this side project game to grasp python better. I'm trying to have the user enter the amount of time the character has to spend busy, then not allow the user to do the same thing until they have completed the original time entered. I have tried a few methods with varying error results from my noob ways. (timestamps, converting input to int and time in different spots, timeDelta)

```
def Gold_mining():
    
    while P.notMining:
    

        print('Welcome to the Crystal mines kid.\nYou will be paid in gold for your labour,\nif lucky you may get some skill points or bonus finds...\nGoodluck in there.')
        print('How long do you wish to enter for?')
        time_mining = int(input("10 Gold Per hour. Max 8 hours --> "))
        



        
        if time_mining > 0 and time_mining <= 8:
            time_started = current_time
            print(f'You will spend {time_mining} hours digging in the mines.')
            P.gold += time_mining * 10
            print(P.gold)
            P.notMining = False
            
            End_Time = (current_time + timedelta(hours = 2))
            print(f'{End_Time} time you exit the mines...')
        elif time_mining > 8:
            print("You can't possibly mine for that long kid, go back and think about it.")
        else:
            print('Invalid')
```

After the set amount of time i would like for it to change the bool value back to false so that you can mine again.

"Crystal Mining" is mapped to a different key for testing so my output says "Inventory" but would say "Crystal Mining" when it works properly and currently looks like this:

```
  *** Page One ***  
Intro Page
02:15:05
  1 Character Stats
  2 Rename Character
  3 Inventory
  4 Change Element
  5 Menu
  6 Exit
Num: 3
Welcome to the Crystal mines kid.
You will be paid in gold for your labour,
if lucky you may get some skill points or bonus finds...
Goodluck in there.
How long do you wish to enter for?
10 Gold Per hour. Max 8 hours --> 1
You will spend 1 hours digging in the mines.
60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python ideas\input_as_always.py", line 176, in <module>
    intro.pageInput()
  File "H:\Python ideas\input_as_always.py", line 45, in pageInput
    self.pageOptions[pInput]['entry']()
  File "H:\Python ideas\input_as_always.py", line 134, in Gold_mining
    End_Time = (current_time + timedelta(hours = 2))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str
```

Comment: Post a  [mcve], but the problem with the error shown is that `current_time` is a string, not a `datetime` object.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestions on how to correct that?

Comment: You haven’t shown code that sets current_time. It should be a date time object if you want to add a time_delta object to it. Read the [mcve] link.